# Unable to enter text into element using setValue in nightwatch using javascript

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Here is my **nightwatch.conf.js**

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["D:/project/tests"],
  "output_folder" : "D:/project/reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "D:/project/selenium/seleniumstandalone.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "D:/project/lib/chromedriver.exe",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver": "D:/project/lib/geckodriver.exe"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {

       "browserName" : "firefox",

      "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }


    }
  }
```

here is my code in the test :

```
module.exports = {
  'Demo test Google' : function (client) {
    client
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .waitForElementPresent('body', 1000)
      .pause(1000)
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
      .waitForElementPresent('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
      .click('button[name=btnG]')
      .pause(1000)

      .end();
  }
};
```

The result of test:

D:\project>node nightwatch.js -t tests/p.js

Starting selenium server... started - PID: 2772 
[P] Test Suite ==================

Running: Demo Google 
√ Element  was present after 20 milliseconds.
√ Element  was present after 30 milliseconds. 
OK. 2 assertions passed. (15.585s)

All the tests are passed but **setValue()** is not entering text in the element.

Comment: Please post the error you have , update your code representation and add more details about it.

Comment: D:\project>node nightwatch.js -t tests/p.js
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  2772

[P] Test Suite
==================

Running:  Demo Google
 √ Element <body> was present after 20 milliseconds.
 √ Element <input[name="email"]> was present after 30 milliseconds.

OK. 2 assertions passed. (15.585s)       this is what i got in my cmd but setValue() is not entering text in the element

Comment: so you never see "nightwatch" being typed in to the search bar? did you try the same test with another browser say chrome?

Comment: @daredadevil no i didn't tried , someone gave me a task to do this i don't know anything about nightwatch so if you don't mind ,can you please help me its urgent

Comment: Have you tried on other browsers? are they behaving the same ?